# How to convert opencv mat grayscale image to pytorch tensor?

Tags: c++, opencv, pytorch

I want to convert cv::Mat class into torch::Tensor class and put them into CNN module of libtorch for prediction. How should I convert Mat class to Tensor class? My CNN module is a pt file generated using the mnist training set. The training image of this mnist training set is single-channel gray image. If I want to test, it should load a gray mat image, so I want to change the single-channel gray image converted to tensor. The language I use is c++。

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to copy memory from cv::Mat object to torch::Tensor object:

```
    cv::Mat img =cv::imread("path/to/file.png");
    cv::cvtColor(img,img,cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    torch::Tensor tensor = torch::empty({img.cols,img.rows},torch::TensorOptions().dtype(torch::kUInt8));
    memcpy(tensor.data<void>(),img.data,img.rows*img.cols);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I encountered another problem. My prediction function can predict 256 tensor pictures, but it cannot predict one tensor picture.

Comment: I am not an expert in torch, I just showed the way to copy data from one object to other. There could be some mistakes in data types or dimensions order. To see some code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. Finally, I found a solution. Before, I didn't know much about the tensor class. A tensor has four elements, which are the number, height, width, and byte depth of the image.

```
  std::string p1 = "D:";
  std::string p2;
  std::cin >> p2;
  std::string p3 = ".png";
  std::string path = p1 + p2 + p3;
  cv::Mat image = cv::imread(path,cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
  torch::Tensor img_tensor = torch::from_blob(image.data, { 1, image.rows, image.cols, 1 }, torch::kByte);
  img_tensor = img_tensor.permute({ 0, 3, 1, 2 });
  img_tensor = img_tensor.toType(torch::kFloat);
  img_tensor = img_tensor.div(255);
  auto a = net->predict(img_tensor);
  std::cout << a.argmax() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this combination for convert openCV Images to tensor of libtorch.
I use libtorch-cxx11-abi-shared-with-deps-1.10.0+cu102 and C++ STANDARD 14.

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("test.jpeg")// Any image to load...
cv::Mat input; // Conversion of image in to color format or any format [1].
cv::cvtColor(image, input,  cv::COLOR_RGBGRAY); 
//cv::cvtColor(image, input, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);    //or for color  
                               
std::cout << "Check image dimentions" <<std::endl;  // Check conversion
std::cout << "pixel dim x: "<<input.rows<< std::endl;
std::cout << "pixel dim x: "<<input.cols<< std::endl;
//Image to tensor conversion.
torch::Tensor tensor_image = torch::from_blob(input.data, {1, input.rows, input.cols, 3}, torch::kByte);
//Permute data structure to Tensor format.
tensor_image = tensor_image.permute({0, 3, 1, 2});
tensor_image = tensor_image.toType(torch::kFloat);
tensor_image = tensor_image.div(255);
//load to CUDA device if need...
tensor_image = tensor_image.to(torch::kCUDA);
std::cout<<"Img to Tensor converted!"<<std::endl;
```

[1] https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html